# Why are these javascript objects equal?

Tags: javascript, object, equality

I've learned that in javascript, objects are passed by reference, and as a result, checking equality of two objects is not as simple as `objA === objB`, even if those objects have the same properties.   Why then, in the context of the browser, does the following code equate to true?

`window.self === window.top`

Both window.self and window.top will return the window object.  I suspect the answer has something to do with the window object having a particular type of type `Window`, but I'm hoping for someone to elaborate on specifically how the object equality is different in this case vs. regular object comparison.

Comment: In your test case those properties simply refer to the same object, `window`. If you'd check that equality in an iframe, you'd get `false`.

Comment: Teemu is absolutely right. When in the top level frame, you can compare 4 objects, and they are all the same reference: `window` === `window.self` === `window.parent` === `window.top`. `window` and `window.self` are always the same object. `window.top` is always the topmost frame in a window (or tab), `window.parent` gives you the parent frame, when you have nested `<frameset>` or `<iframe>` elements in your html.

Comment: window, top, self, and (sometimes) this, are all the same thing by different names, except in certain circumstances.